# Listing Stripe refunds between dates

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.net

Using the Stripe API, I'm struggling to work out how to list refunds between two dates.

I can list `charges` between two dates, but as the refund can come at a date significantly after the charge date, it is not good.

Thanks for anyone who can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [List All Balance History](https://stripe.com/docs/api#balance_history) API and pass `type: "refund"` to only list the refunds and also pass the `created` hash based on the dates I want to limit my search to and you should get all the balance transactions associated with a refund created between those two dates.

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary with dates is working for me even though the API docs don't show this as an option for Refund.list:

```
epoch_dict = {'lt': 1496505600, 'gte': 1496502000}
refunds = stripe.Refund.list(limit=100, created=epoch_dict)
```

Comment: This kind of operations are very fundamentals, how did you find out about this `created` kwarg and how to use it properly? I didn't see anything like this in the docs

Comment: It's documented (for payouts at least) https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/list#list_payouts-created